# Launch another instance of Java app on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I have a Mac Java app bundle that has problems opening an OpenGL window from a SWT dialog in a single process. [It just doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386875/opening-a-lwjgl-window-from-a-swt-app-on-mac).

To solve this problem I would like to open a SWT dialog in one instance of the Java app and then have it launch another instance of itself with a parameter saying "this time open the OpenGL window". The part I don't know how to do is finding out what "itself" is on a Mac.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adapt this Swing based [Launcher](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/c81f8c5f269e22e5) that uses 
exec() to run programs in a separate JVM. If you need to include your own dynamic libraries, you might be able to use one of the relative path symbols described in `man dyld` under the heading [*Dynamic Library Loading*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).